# Prestashop: Get taxes value by webservice, how are they relationed

Tags: api, prestashop

I'm having some issues getting Taxes value for products:

each product for products endpoint has this value:
   "id_tax_rules_group": "XX"

taxes:

```
        {
            "id": ZZ,
            "rate": "10.000",
            "active": "1",
            "deleted": "0",
            "name": "TVA FR 10%"
        },
```

tax_rules:

```
        {
            "id": YY,
            "rate": "10.000",
            "active": "1",
            "deleted": "0",
            "name": "TVA FR 10%"
        },
```

tax_rule_groups:

```
        {
            "id": XX,
            "name": "FR Taux standard (20%)",
            "active": "1",
            "deleted": "0",
            "date_add": "2017-05-23 08:17:13",
            "date_upd": "2017-05-23 08:17:13"
        },
```

So, the question is: How are they related? If I need the taxes rate field, how do I know which id it has?

The only relations found are:

```
product[id_tax_rules_group] == tax_rule_groups["id"]
product[id_tax_rules_group] != taxes["rate"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taxes in prestashop are related on this way:

The *tax_rule_group* are related with the *tax_rule* with the field *id_tax_rules_group*:

```
-tax_rule_groups(tax_rule_group):
  0.- id
  1.- name
  2.- active
  3.- deleted
  4.- date_add
  5.- date_upd
-tax_rules(tax_rule):
  0.- id
  1.- id_tax_rules_group
  2.- id_state
  3.- id_country
  4.- zipcode_from
  5.- zipcode_to
  6.- id_tax
  7.- behavior
  8.- description
```

As you can see, the tax_rules are related with the taxes using *id_tax*, so that means that there are only one tax per *tax_rule*, and as you can see, the *tax_rule* related *id_tax*, *id_country* and *id_state*.

In conclusion, seeing this i supposed that the relation is that the *tax_rule_groups* is an agrupation of the taxes of countries and states (*tax_rules*), i have explained it?

Comment: The the problem is that I'm getting different info from tax_rules, as they don't match with your example.

Comment: Can you give an example? I'll try to finde the problem. Regards.